# Не доходят данные до Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Собственно вопрос: отправляю данные, приходит пустой ответ. Смотрю в панели хрома данные оправлены. Вставил `alert` ни он не сработал, ни ошибка передачи не вылезла.
Вывожу обратно просто вардампом весь пост что бы посмотреть что пришло.

```
function up_db() {
        //массив, который будем передавать
        var msg = [];
        $("tr").each(function(idx, row){
            // проверка, что коллекация найденных строк не пуста
            if($(row).find("input:checked").length){
                //строка отмечена, добавить данные в массив
                msg.push({
                        //cellValue: parseInt($(row).find("td").eq(1).text()),
                        taxes: $(row).find(".taxes").val(),
                        id: $(row).find(".id").val()
                    });
            }
        });
    //var msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
    console.log(msg);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'update_db.php',
        data: msg,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("weofi");
            $('#resultat').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, str) {
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
}
```

При таком коде, консоль показывает что отправляем объект который должен быть преобразован в `JSON`. Но отправляется, почему то, `undefined`. Если в пхп части стоит `json_decode`,  то говорит что пришел массив, а не строка. Если просто вардамп, то возвращает пустой массив. Если раскоментить строку `var msg = JSON.stringify(msg);`, то уходит все нормально судя по панели хрома. Но вардамп показывает: пустой результат, как вроде ничего не дошло и `alert` тоже не срабатывает.
 Подскажите, где ошибка закралась?

Comment: Вы отправляете на сервер?

Comment: да на сервер другие аяксы нормально проходят.

Comment: функция вызыввается при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: проверьте переводы строк в update_db.php после <?php ?> и вообще неплохо бы показать содержимое этого файла

Comment: `<?php
//$str = json_encode($_POST);
$str = json_decode($_POST);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($str);
echo "</pre>";`

Comment: пробовал разные типы выводов и переводов нет

Comment: смотрите серверную часть. На сервере может быть ошибка обработки данных и ответа никакого не получите. Попробуйте сократить серверный обработчик до короткого - на запрос отправить безусловный ответ, остальное закомментируйте.

Comment: короче некуда пробовал и с декодеэенкоде и без них просто вардампом.

Comment: data — данные, которые будут отправлены на сервер. Они должны быть представлены в объектом, в формате: {fName1:value1, fName2:value2, ...}. http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_JSON-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85

Comment: они так и представлены только в объекте. Вручную я их не забью так как их переменное к-во     `msg.push({
                        //cellValue: parseInt($(row).find('td').eq(1).text()),
                        taxes: $(row).find('.taxes').val(),
                        id: $(row).find('.id').val()
                    });` они здесь задаются. проверяю через консоль отображаются нормально.

Comment: извините, работка отвлекает. разобрались?

Comment: да нет пока не разобрался еще когда разбираюсь пишу правильный ответ или отмечаю наиболее помогший для остальных участников

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решилось все до банальности просто расскоментил строку и  поменял имя переменой дя бесконфликтности `var js = JSON.stringify(msg);` убрал тип данных json, и как ни странно пришлось объект дополнительно присвоить переменной (как обычно отправляют пару переменная-значение) хотя во всех мануалах написано что объект отправляется как сам объект с определенным типом данных как писал выше @Dmitry OnGamer и его ненужно ничему присваивать. `data: {data:js}`